# how to make layout non touchable

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a relativelayout or linearlayout for an activity, that takes up 50% of the screen. I want to make it such that the other 50%, the user is able to interact with the 'things' beneath. For example, the activity layout appears on top of browser. I want the user to be able to continue scrolling the browser beneath.

Is this possible? I tried these but not working.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [GirdLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) beside your top layout, and put another scrollview below.
For example:

```
<GridLayout...> // define two rows, 50% each
   <RelativeLayout> // put this on the first row
...
   </RelativeLayout>

   <ScrollView>// put this on the second row
...
   </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Scrolling browser beneath is just an example. What I need is able to interact. Like clicking on another app beneath

Comment: Sorry, I answered without reading well the question. Now I understand, you want to create a layout like "transparent" while touching, right?.